# Trouble with Rectangles overlapping instead of touching XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, collision-detection

I'm making the skeleton for the typical BubbleShooter game in XNA, and I'm having issues with my collision detection algorithm, which is explained in the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIuoi.png)

Depending on where the colliding Rectangle position is at the moment of collision, a new position is assigned to the colliding Bubble.

The issue appears when I shoot a bubble and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvf2y.png) happens at the moment of collision.
I have run the debug step by step, and the moment when the collision happens is exactly like the picture, so my algorithm fails.
I tried to post the images directly, but it seems I can't since I'm still a new user here. Sorry about that.

Is there a way I can detect **exactly** *when* the boundaries of the Rectangles touch each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a per pixel collision instead, it is explained here:

[Click here](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_perpixel)

Comment: It worked **exactly** how I need it to work. You should get a medal. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand, your problem is that you miss the exact moment of collision ?

I guess you are computing collisions in a discreet way, ie. even if your algorithm runs 60 times a second, it is *only* 60 times when a second could be subdivised in an infinity of *instants*.

The simple (and bad) solution is to make your objects move slower.

The good one implies to retrieve what happens *between* the frames. you will need some kind of direction vector and the object speed. With both these values, you can determine where and when the collision did occur.

You will also need the elapsed time between frames. This is the purpose of the GameTime object : it has a property "ElpasedGameTime", which has a property "TotalElapsedMilliseconds".

MSDN Documentation on GameTime class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime.elapsedgametime.aspx

Some reading material on Wikipedia about collision detection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection#A_posteriori_.28discrete.29_versus_a_priori_.28continuous.29

"A priori" and "A posteriori" detection : that's the keywords you might be missing.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that. Messing with Time so I could to analyse a discrete collision, instead of a continuum one. I also think is a really *dirty* implementation, and I will take it as a last resource.
I think, I'll try per pixel collision. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to test it right now but you should try to limit your number of collisions per frame to 1.
With a counter when it enters the update part if one collision has been detected block all other collision for the same frame.
This way if your projectile its the bottom part, your code for

```
                if(hitBottomPart)
                {
                  // Logic
                }
```

part will execute in this same frame before the projectile has time to hit another rectangle of the texture.
Although this is just a guess.
Good luck with your game ! Collisions are  always a pain to implement.

Comment: Yes, I had thought a bit about this issue too. I'll take your advice into consideration. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.
I saw the same problem in a brickbreaker type of game where the ball had time to hit many bricks in a second because the collisions where not limited.
That solution did the trick and it's easier to implement than to change the whole collision system for a Pixel per Pixel.
(Although Pixel per Pixel is Much more accurate)